# Best way to let child view know when it is inserted in the DOM

Tags: backbone.js

What is the best way to let subviews/child views know when they are already in the DOM?

Consider we have following hierarchy of views:

```
MainView
   SubView
      ChildView
```

Here for example `MainView` is already in the DOM. Then as a part of `render` process `MainView` creates `SubView` which in turns creates `ChildView`.

As a result `ChildView` won't be in the DOM until `MainView` finishes its' rendering. And I need to know (via event or handler) when it is inserted and displayed.

The most straightforward answer is for `MainView` to trigger some event when it is done rendering. If it were the only case where I needed it - it would be alright. But there are lots of places and in general suddenly subviews dictate their parents what to do, probably not good.

***Update***:
In what cases this is required? When we are using widgets which expect element to be in the DOM (to get height, etc). In example: Accordion widget, jqGrid. So the correct time to init them when their container is already in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your use case is but I'm assuming its finding a DOM element within the Childview and manipulating it. In this case, it would not matter if its in the DOM or not.

What I typically do is grab the reference to the element - `$el`

and then find the sub-element

```
$target = $el.find('.target')
```

This has the added benefit of only allowing me to grab classes or ids within the ChildView ensuring a proper management of views.

Comment: So I've actually used the nanoScroller plugin and initialized it using my method since its a Jquery library...seems to work fine for me. This might help for your height / width problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225869/how-can-i-get-size-height-width-information-in-backbone-views

Comment: Following your link, accepted answer: "Try getting the height after you attach it". nanoScroller may be a bad example. Changed to Accordion :)